# Is it possible to change the default COUNT value of tail and head?

Tags: tail, head

The `less` command accepts its defaults with an environment variable `LESS`, so you can

```
export LESS='-F -g -i -M -R -S -w -X -z-4'
```

at the beginning of your session.

Is it possible to change the default lines count returned by `head` and `tail` in a similar fashion?

***An alias is not an option***, because it breaks explicit option setting (e.g. in a script):

```
head -n 15 -5
```

fails with an error in both GNU and busybox `head` at least.

Comment: What do you mean with "breaks explicit option setting"? What exactly will break if you set something explicitly?

Comment: From the info page for head you can read that using `-5` is obsolete: `For compatibility 'head' also supports an obsolete option syntax
'-COUNTOPTIONS', which is recognized only if it is specified first.` At least for `head` from coreutils.

Comment: Still, old scripts may be using that form and an alias breaks their execution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since the old style options like `-5`, `+5` are only recognised as the first argument, you could do:

```
head()
  case $1 in
    ([-+][0-9]*) command head "$@";;
    (*) command head -n 15 "$@"
  esac
```

That will affect the `head`s invoked by your current shell.

If you want to affect all head invocations, you'd need to write it as a script that appears first in your `$PATH`:

```
mkdir -p ~/bin && cat > ~/bin/head << \EOF &&
#! /bin/sh -
case $1 in
  ([-+][0-9]*) ;;
  (*) set -- -n 15 "$@"
esac
exec /usr/bin/head "$@"
EOF
chmod +x ~/bin/head
PATH=~/bin:$PATH export PATH
```

Answer (score 1):

Use an alias, e.g. `alias head="/usr/bin/head -n 15"` (no, it will not break any later options).

Use a function, e.g.

```
head() {
  /usr/bin/head -n 15 "$@"
}
```

Cobble up your own, as the head(1) info for GNU suggests, i.e., use `sed 15q` in a script.

Comment: It breaks it in the case of `head -n 15 -2` with both busybox and GNU `head` and `tail` at least

Comment: Breaks BSD `head` and `tail` shipped with OSX too

Answer (score 0):

Using an alias is certainly an option if you are working with `head` from coreutils version 8.13. That is because

```
head -n 5 -n 15 file_name
```

will give you the first 15 lines of `file_name` (assuming that file has enough lines. The second `-n` option overrides the first.

So you can create an alias:

```
alias head="/usr/bin/head -n 5"
```

to set the default to five and then use:

```
head -n 15 file_name
```

The same holds true for `tail`.

Comment: It breaks it in the case of `head -n 15 -2` with both busybox and GNU `head` and `tail` at least.

Comment: Breaks BSD `head` and `tail` shipped with OSX too

Comment: @StephaneChazelas `-2` is obsolete syntax according to the `head` `info` page. `head --help and `man help` don't even mention that anymore.

Comment: Yes, but still used in many scripts. GNU once removed support for those but had to bring it back as it was causing outrage

Answer (score -1):

the best way is to do it "on the fly"

```
 sudo tail -f /path/to/file
```

will display the last 10 lines (live) of the mentioned file [10 lines is the default for tail]

you can also display multiple files

```
sudo tail -f -n 20 /path/to/file1 /path/to/file2
```

will display two seperate blocks of text each with the last 20 lines of file1 and file 2 respectively. I find this one useful for displaying two live "tails" of logfiles whilst doing some other actions and verifying display.